# Should in app purchases be accessible whilst under review - iOS

Tags: ios, ionic-framework, app-store-connect

I've setup an in app purchase subscription in iTunes connect and I'm using the Ionic framework with their 'In App Purchase' plugin (https://ionicframework.com/docs/native/in-app-purchase/). The in app purchase subscriptions are currently under review (showing as 'Waiting for Review') and I can't seem to be able to get anything back from inside the app when referencing the products IDs.

Everything works fine in Android, however, on iOS after getProducts() is returned I am just given a blank array.

I'm trying to work out if this an issue with the app, or if I need to wait for the review process.

Cheers

EDIT: I've just logged in to the iTunes Connect site and checked the contract and it seems like the 'Paid Applications' contract ahsn;t been fully set up. Fingers crossed after sorting that out I'll start getting some results.

Comment: Did you get the list after that?